# Testing Android with Eclipse throws NoClassDefFoundError for MyActivity

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing

When I start my separate android test project via 'android junit test' I always got:

```
Test run failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{my.pack/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
```

this was solved (strange!!) by touching the AndroidManifest.xml

But now when I try to execute this test:

```
public class MyActivityTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {

    public MyActivityTest() {
        // here it fails with NoClassDefFoundError for MyActivity
        super("my.pack", MyActivity.class);
    }

    public void testGetChangedTweetIds() {
       // some tests here
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:239)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:520)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at my.pack.MyActivityTest.<init>(MyActivityTest.java:13)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:87)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:263)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:185)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:373)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4218)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my.pack.MyActivity
... 19 more
```

Although I've added the main project to the build path (via eclipse config) of the test project. Putting the test class within my main project (+ providing the  and ) it works.

Why eclipse has these problems with the recommended approach of a separate test project?

Comment: Which version of Android ?
This constructor is deprecated.

Comment: android 2.2. In this version this constructor does not seem to be deprecated. I've tried different constructors and android 2.3.3 but it does not work (The strange thing was that the first run after eclipse start worked!!??). Any eclipse config hack hint?

Comment: uhm eclipse drives me crazy: again eclipse restart. again the first 3 times worked ... but now the same Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your firs problem indicates that instrumentation is not present, to get the list of available instrumentations use

   $ adb shell pm list instrumentation
2. [public ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 (String pkg, Class activityClass)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html#ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E%29) is deprectated since API level 8
3. If you have a problem with your Eclipse installation run the tests from the command line with

   $ adb shell am instrument [flags]